# Proving entire function to be constant

Tags: complex-analysis, maximum-principle

Given $f$ is an entire function and for any $z\neq0$, $f$ satisfies $f(z)=f(\frac{1}{z^2})$.

The question asks to prove that $f$ is constant.

My approach:
For any $|z|>1$, we have $\dfrac{1}{|z|}<1$ hence by Maximum Modulus Principle, $|f(z)|\leq|f(1)|$ for any $z\in\mathbb{C}$.

But then I got stuck at the next step... Is my direction correct? If yes, what should be the next step? If no, how can we prove $f$ is constant?

Comment: Bounded entire functions are constant.

Comment: If $f$ is entire and bounded, it must be constant. See [Picard's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard_theorem).

Comment: @emacsdrivesmenuts it's  not Picard's theorem,  it's known as Liouville's theorem.

Comment: @emacsdrivesmenuts You mean [Liouville](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(complex_analysis))?  Picard is much harder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By continuity,we have $$\lim_{z\to \infty}f(z)=\lim_{z\to \infty}f\left(\dfrac{1}{z^2}\right)=f(0)$$ If  $\lim_{z\to \infty}f(z)\to \infty$, then $f(0)$ also tends to infinity which contradicts the $f$ is entire.

Thus $f$ is uniformly bounded, and by Liouville's theorem, f is constant.